# Open ports for VPN users

Tags: iptables, vpn, openvpn, pptp

I have been looking around for some time for answer to this, and have yet to find one.

The issue that I am having is that users that are connected to the VPN cannot do the following, as examples:

Connect to Xbox Live

Run a web server through the VPN

Binding the local IP (10.8.0.22 for example) to the web server would succeed, but it is inaccessible from the Internet.

How would I go about opening all ports and allowing traffic to go through them?  I do know that the ports are open.  I read something about this on another post, but am not sure what I would need to do:

Another important thing: you need to add IP routes for the traffic to go between VPN and LAN subnets

I have not had this issue on other servers, just the one that I am running now.  Thanks.